# Access class variable from function in Python

Tags: python, oop

I'm coding my first python game using OOP and I have some problems with the access to class variables.
Specifically, I want to have access to a class variable from a method. For some variables it works, but for a specific boolean variable it does not work:

```
class Player(object):
    eaten = False

    def __init__(self):
          .....

def eat(Player):
    Player.eaten = True
```

The problem is that, when the function is called, *eaten* does not override the variable in the class. For other variables it does correctly what I want though.

EDIT:
If, inside a method in the Class player, I add `print(self.eaten)` after `eat()` is called, it still prints always `False`

```
 class Player(object):
    eaten = False

    def move():
        print(self.eaten)

def eat(Player):
    Player.eaten = True
```

Thank you!

Comment: "[Variables declared inside the class definition, but not inside a method are class or static variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68645/are-static-class-variables-possible)"

Comment: What do you mean by `for other variables it does correctly`? Also are you sure? If I copy and paste your code (giving `__init__` a pass) and call `eat(Player)` then `print(Player.eaten)` I see `True`...

Comment: Yes I am sure, because inside an additional method in `Player`, when I `print(eaten)` it always prints False, even after `eat()` was called

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`eaten` should be a instance variable, not a class variable - you can have some players eaten and others not, and having it as a class variable means it would affect all players, which is probably not what you want.

```
class Player(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.eaten = False

    def move(self):
        if self.eaten:
            print("I have eaten so I can move")
        else:
            print("I can't move! I'm hungry!")

def eat(player, food):
    player.eaten = True # change `eaten` for the player
                        # passed as parameter!

 >>> p = Player() # creates a instance of the Player class
 >>> q = Player() # creates another instance of the Player class
 >>> eat(p, 'apple') # player `p` eates apple
 >>> p.move()
 I have eaten so I can move
 >>> q.move()
 I can't move! I'm hungry!

 print(p.eaten) # will print True
 print(q.eaten) # will print False
```

Comment: `def eat()` needs to be outside the class, since I pass actually two classes in it, so I cannot do it inside an other class. It is indeed `def eat(Player, Food)`.

Comment: @MauroComi ok, I edited my answer, but this is confusing! You should pass instances around, not classes, and you should use lower case variable names for instances. See my answer.

Comment: @maurock It may be useful for you to look into [Composition](https://realpython.com/inheritance-composition-python/#whats-composition)

Answer (score 1):

When you create a class, you want to create *instance variables* for stuff like this. Instance variables are variables that can be different for each instance of the Class you are creating. You do this by defining it as a variable "self.var" in the init method, like so

```
class Player(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.eaten = False
```

This sets the default value of `eaten` for every new instance of Player to be `False`. Whenever we do something like `foo = Player()`, there is an instance variable like `foo.eaten` which defaults to being `False`. Now if we want to update that with a method, we need to reference the instance of `Player` whose instance variable we are updating, usually with the parameter called `self`

```
class Player(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.eaten = False

    def eat(self):
        self.eaten = True
```

Now when we do `foo.eat()`, Python passes in `foo` as the first parameter to the function `eat`, meaning `self.eaten` is really looking at `foo.eaten`. Therefore when we say `self.eaten = True` we are setting the instance variable of `foo.eaten` to `True`.

Answer (score 0):

When you're calling the function, you're passing an object, not the class. So, you are assigning the variable on the instance. Change your function to

def eat(player):
    type(player).eaten = True

where `type(player)` returns the actual `Player` class

Comment: It is already as you suggested. It is a method outside th class, already `Player.eaten = True`

Comment: @MauroComi: how do you call that function??

Comment: in the main `eat(player1)`, being `player1 = Player()`